# Remove custom permalink structure from custom post type without modifying register_post_type() directly

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I'm using a custom permalink structure for my posts, `/blog/%postname%/`. I installed a plugin which registers a custom post type, `glossary`. I don't want this post type to use the custom permalinks structure that standard posts are using. I believe that setting `'rewrite' => array('with_front' => false)` when the post type is registered will accomplish this. The problem is that the post type is being registered by the plugin, so I can't modify the function directly within the plugin's code, at least not if I want an upgrade-proof fix. How can I add arguments to the array through my theme's functions.php file, rather than the plugin's code?

Here's the function the plugin uses to register the post type, in case that's helpful:

```
public function register_post_types(){
    register_post_type( 'glossary', array(
        'public'               => true,
        'menu_position'        => 105,
        'has_archive'          => true,
        'supports'             => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'author', 'excerpt' ),
        'labels' => array(
            'name'               => __( 'Glossary Terms',                   'wp-glossary' ),
            'singular_name'      => __( 'Glossary Term',                    'wp-glossary' ),
            'add_new'            => __( 'Add New Term',                     'wp-glossary' ),
            'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Glossary Term',            'wp-glossary' ),
            'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Glossary Term',               'wp-glossary' ),
            'new_item'           => __( 'Add New Glossary Term',            'wp-glossary' ),
            'view_item'          => __( 'View Glossary Term',               'wp-glossary' ),
            'search_items'       => __( 'Search Glossary Terms',            'wp-glossary' ),
            'not_found'          => __( 'No Glossary Terms found',          'wp-glossary' ),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Glossary Terms found in trash', 'wp-glossary' )
        ),
        'register_meta_box_cb' => array( $this, 'meta_boxes' ),
        'rewrite'              => array( 'slug' => sanitize_title( _x( 'glossary', 'rewrite slug', 'wp-glossary' ) ) ),
    ) );

    add_filter( 'manage_glossary_posts_columns',       array($this, 'manage_glossary_posts_columns') );
    add_action( 'manage_glossary_posts_custom_column', array($this, 'manage_glossary_posts_custom_column'), 10, 2 );

    add_action( 'save_post',   array(&$this, 'save_glossary_post'), 10, 2 );
    add_filter( 'the_content', array(&$this, 'the_content'),        10, 2 );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this to modify the definition

```
$args = get_post_type_object("glossary");
$args->rewrite = array("with_front" => FALSE);
register_post_type($args->name, $args);
```

this has to be done after the call of "register_post_types()" of the plugin